# Flask SqlAlchemy on google app engine and google cloud sql

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, flask, google-cloud-sql

Any python example thread for beginners to start using google app engine with flask and sql alchemy, to access google cloud sql?
Especially from configuration point of view!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SQLAlchemy be used with Google Cloud SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763171/can-sqlalchemy-be-used-with-google-cloud-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question answered on SO:
[Can SQLAlchemy be used with Google Cloud SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763171/can-sqlalchemy-be-used-with-google-cloud-sql)

SQLAlchemy docs:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms