# Appengine to MySQL Database hosted in Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine-python

Somebody knows if is it possible connect an application from Appengine to a mysql database hosted in compute engine?

I'm trying to do this with python and i have this error:

> Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)

I'm using SqlAlchemy ORM which use the next configuration:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root@ip/database')
```

and locally works but when i deploy the application to appengine doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine, by default, runs code in a [sandboxed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime) environment, meaning that certain aspects of the Python runtime environment are restricted, or respond differently than they would otherwise.  One of these aspects is outbound network connectivity—while GAE [supports sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/), there are certain restrictions, and sockets are only available for paid apps.

The [recommended options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/storage) for storing information in a GAE app include the [App Engine Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/storage#app_engine_datastore), [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/storage#google_cloud_sql), and [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/storage#google_cloud_storage). Google Cloud SQL is MySQL, and [works with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10900826/1068191), so that's probably your best option.

If you absolutely need to run your own MySQL server (rather than using Google Cloud SQL) and connect to it from a GAE app, the other option is to use the [managed VM environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/python/about-the-managed-vm-environment), which permits unrestricted network access (since it's essentially a Google Compute Engine VM with the App Engine runtime on top).